# Как сделать 404 редирект если такого url не существует?

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать редирект на кастомную 404 страницу в laravel ? 
Или-же как подключить middleware в шаблон errors/404.blade.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле app/Exceptions/Handler.php есть метод  **public function render($request, Exception $exception)**, в нем и можете сделать проверку instanceof и отдать нужное представление для рендера

Comment: Спасибо большое, так и сделал уже.